# What is the best way to post to Twitter from a django app?

Tags: django, twitter

What I want to do is pretty straightforward. I have a site powered by django. I want to have the site automatically post to twitter any time a new object is created and saved in the database. What is the absolute best way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is the following:

First, handle the `post_save` signal from Django.  Note that `post_save` passes your handler a boolean parameter `created` to let you know whether it's a new object that was saved.

- http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/

Then, call the `python-twitter` library's `PostUpdate` function within your handler to notify on twitter:

- http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/

Comment: The python-twitter plugin is amazing! 2 seconds and you are done!

Answer (score 4):

Try using the function `post_to_twitter()` from this: http://www.djangosnippets.org/snippets/1339/